# I have the following XML file. I want to create tables dynamically based on testcategory name(in ths case 3 tables) using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Assuming your XML will be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
  <finaloutputxml>
    <execresult starttime="01.01.1970 05:30:00" endtime="01.01.1970 05:30:00" duration="263">
      <devicedetails>
        <devicemodel>SCH-R760U</devicemodel>
        <androidversion>4.1.2</androidversion>
        <basebandversion>S:R760.01 K.FK22</basebandversion>
        <kernelversion>3.0.31-1030861-eng root@QBAGENT131 #3 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 8 18:49:29 KST 2013</kernelversion>
        <buildnumber>SCH-R760U-eng 4.1.2 JZO54K U1_TEST test-keys</buildnumber>
     </devicedetails>
    <testsummary>
        <categorycount>3</categorycount>
        <totaltc>27</totaltc>
        <passcount>26</passcount>
        <failcount>0</failcount>
        <errorcount>1</errorcount>
    </testsummary>
    <testcategory name="Open" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:53" duration="6128" count="21.0" errCount="0" failCount="0" passCount="1">
        <testcase name="TC_Open_001" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Open_002" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>Fail</result>
           <author>B</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Open_003" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>C</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
    </testcategory>

    <testcategory name="Close" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:53" duration="6128" count="21.0" errCount="0" failCount="0" passCount="1">
        <testcase name="TC_Close_001" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
            <result>pass</result>
           <author>D</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Close_002" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Close_003" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
    </testcategory>

    <testcategory name="Start" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:53" duration="6128" count="21.0" errCount="0" failCount="0" passCount="1">
        <testcase name="TC_Start_001" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Start_002" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
        <testcase name="TC_Start_003" starttime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" endtime="22.07.2013 12:03:55" duration="485">
           <result>pass</result>
           <author>A</author>
           <description>This is TC description</description>
           <priority>High</priority>
           <returntype>String</returntype>
           <precondition>precondition</precondition>
         </testcase>
    </testcategory>
</execresult>
```

the output will look like

Category Details
                     Open
TC Name       Start_Time         End_Time        Duration
TC_Open_001 22.07.2013 12:03:55 22.07.2013 12:03:55 485
TC_Open_002 22.07.2013 12:03:57 22.07.2013 12:03:58 499
TC_Open_003 22.07.2013 12:04:00 22.07.2013 12:04:00 111

```
                 Close
```

TC Name       Start_Time         End_Time        Duration
TC_Close_001 22.07.2013 12:03:55 22.07.2013 12:03:55 485
TC_Close_002 22.07.2013 12:03:57 22.07.2013 12:03:58 499
TC_Close_003 22.07.2013 12:04:00 22.07.2013 12:04:00 111

```
                 Start
```

TC Name       Start_Time         End_Time        Duration
TC_Start_001 22.07.2013 12:03:55 22.07.2013 12:03:55 485
TC_Start_002 22.07.2013 12:03:57 22.07.2013 12:03:58 499
TC_Start_003 22.07.2013 12:04:00 22.07.2013 12:04:00 111

I have done as below

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.0"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
      <div>
       <div style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%;">Test Results</div>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="finaloutputxml/execresult/devicedetails"/>

      <div style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%;"></div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="finaloutputxml/execresult/testsummary"/>

     <div style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%;">Category Details</div>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="finaloutputxml/execresult/testcategory"/>

      <div style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%;">Testcase Details</div>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="finaloutputxml/execresult/testcategory/testcase"/>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="devicedetails">
    <table align="left" border="1" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <caption style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: silver; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Device Details</caption>
        <tr>
           <th colspan="2">
             <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/@name"/>
            </th>
         </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>Device Model</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="devicemodel"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>Andriod Version</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="androidversion"/>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>Baseband Version</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="basebandversion"/>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Kernel Version</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="kernelversion"/>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Build Number</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="buildnumber"/>
             </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testsummary">
      <table align="left" border="1" style="margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 10pt;">
      <caption style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: silver; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Test Summary</caption>
       <tr>
         <th colspan="2">
         <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/@name"/>
         </th>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>Category Count</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="categorycount"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>Total Count</td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="totaltc"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
         <td>Pass Count</td>
         <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="passcount"/>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>Fail Count</td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="failcount"/>
         </td>
      </tr>

     <tr>
       <td>Error Count</td>
       <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="errorcount"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testcategory">
      <table border="1" style="margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%">
        <caption style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: silver; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
         <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </caption>
        <tr>
         <th>Testcase Name</th>
         <th>Start Time</th>
         <th>End Time</th>
         <th>Duration</th>
       </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase"/>
       </table> 
 </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="testcase">
      <tr>
         <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="@starttime"/>
        </td>

         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@endtime"/>
         </td>

         <td>
             <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
         </td>
       </tr>
  </xsl:template> 

    <!--  <xsl:template match="testcase">
      <xsl:template match="finaloutputxml/execresult/testcategory/testcase">
          <table border="1" style="margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%">
             <caption style="font-size: 12pt; background-color: silver; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
               <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
             </caption>
          <tr>
            <th>Result</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="Result"/> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="author"/> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="description"/> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="priority"/> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Return Type</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="returntype"/> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Precondition</th>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="precondition"/> </td>
         </tr>
      </table>  
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>  --> 
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question might be more html/css than xslt

Comment: Your XSLT seems fine, but can you give a bit more detail as to what your actual problem is, as I am not clear what 'spaces' you are talking about between the tables. Perhaps you could show your expected output here too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of rows might vary for each section, one way to account for this problem is to divide up the work according to the hierarchy of the XML document. The Device Details table and Test Summary table should appear side-by-side below the Test Category tables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.0"
                doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>

    <xsl:variable name="header_style">
        <xsl:text>font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 1em; width: 40%;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="caption_style">
        <xsl:text>font-size: 12pt; background-color: silver; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="detail_table_style">
        <xsl:text>margin-right: 5pt; float: left;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="div_style">
        <xsl:text>clear: both; margin-bottom: 1em;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="summary_table_style">
        <xsl:text>margin-right: 10pt; float: left;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="cat_table_style">
        <xsl:text>width: 40%</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div style="{$div_style}">
                    <div style="{$header_style}">Category Details</div>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="finaloutputxml/execresult"/>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="execresult">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="testcategory"/>
        <div style="{$div_style}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="devicedetails"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="testsummary"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testcategory">
        <div style="{$div_style}">
            <table border="1" style="{$cat_table_style}">
                <caption style="{$caption_style}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Testcase Name</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase" mode="summary"/>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="{$div_style}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="testcase" mode="details"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testcase" mode="summary">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@starttime"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@endtime"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testcase" mode="details">       
        <table  border="1" style="{$detail_table_style}">
            <caption style="{$caption_style}">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(parent::node()/@name, ': ', @name)"/>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Result</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="result"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Priority</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="priority"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Return Type</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="returntype"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Preconditon</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="precondition"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="devicedetails">
        <table border="1" style="{$summary_table_style}">
            <caption style="{$caption_style}">Device Details</caption>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/@name"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Device Model</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="devicemodel"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Andriod Version</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="androidversion"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Baseband Version</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="basebandversion"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kernel Version</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="kernelversion"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Build Number</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="buildnumber"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="testsummary">
        <table border="1" style="{$summary_table_style}">
            <caption style="{$caption_style}">Test Summary</caption>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()/@name"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Category Count</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="categorycount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Count</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="totaltc"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pass Count</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="passcount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fail Count</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="failcount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Error Count</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="errorcount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot **user2032915**...It works fine for me...can you tell me if I want to create one more table after these tables how can I do so? ...example with any dummy table with structure only will also do..

Comment: @**user2032915** I have updated my xml...I want one more table below these tables named as TestCase Details...these tables will start with a lebel as category name and a testcase name as header row and in row we can show the details of the testcase tag(ie, result,author,description, category etc). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your requirements. Could you post an example output of the TestCaseDetails table?

Comment: @**user2032915** <table width="100%" align="left" border="1">
<tr class="headerRowBG">
<th colspan="2">TC_delete_002</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%" class="headerRowText">Result</td><td width="80%">Success</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerRowText">Description</td><td>Some description adad sfs dfd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerRowText">Category</td><td>Open</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerRowText">Parameter</td><td>filename</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="headerRowText">Return Type</td><td>String</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerRowText">Prority</td><td>High</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: @**user2032915** or you can have any table with some colunms below the tables you have created.while I am adding a table it is displaying rightside of the existing table not in below the table..

Comment: It can be done; however, you don't have the data in your current XML document to populate the right-side table. I cannot imagine how to parse the XML document with XSLT without knowing where this data may appear.

Comment: By the way, I modified the above XSLT code to create separate tables for each category.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is what I wanted...I have updated  my xml to add some data to the testcase tag for the testcase details table...Please try to add one more table as testcase details below the  tables you have created...

Comment: @**user2032915** I have updated my recent xml and the way I have tryed my xsl....I am expecting some tables with test case details at end with of my html page...The structure of the table is mentioned in my comented .xsl code...Please have a look and plz suggest with ur update/comments....

Comment: I hope this update is closer to what you are looking for. The detail tables will expand the right per the number of test cases. If you want a different look, you will need to adjust the style attribute of the DIV wrapping them.